# como obtener color en rgb de una ventana de 64bits en visual studio c#

Tags: c#

mi pregunta es relacionada a como podria obtener el valor en RGB de un pixel de determinada ventana, lo que pasa es que en una ventana con de 32 bits mi condigo funciona muy bien, pero cuando lo intento en una de 64bits todos los colores los capta negros, muchas gracias por la ayuda generada, dejo el codigo que utilizo apra lockk y unlock bitmap y tambien el proceso de obtencion del pixel.

```
  public void LockBits()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get width and height of bitmap
                Width = source.Width;
                Height = source.Height;

                // get total locked pixels count
                int PixelCount = Width * Height;

                // Create rectangle to lock
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

                // get source bitmap pixel format size
                Depth = System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(source.PixelFormat);

                // Check if bpp (Bits Per Pixel) is 8, 24, or 32
                if (Depth != 8 && Depth != 24 && Depth != 32)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Only 8, 24 and 32 bpp images are supported.");
                    
                }

                // Lock bitmap and return bitmap data
                bitmapData = source.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                             source.PixelFormat);

                // create byte array to copy pixel values
                int step = Depth / 8;
                Pixels = new byte[PixelCount * step];
                Iptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

                // Copy data from pointer to array
                Marshal.Copy(Iptr, Pixels, 0, Pixels.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No se Bloqueo el mapa de datos", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unlock bitmap data
        /// </summary>
        public void UnlockBits()
        {
            try
            {
                // Copy data from byte array to pointer
                Marshal.Copy(Pixels, 0, Iptr, Pixels.Length);

                // Unlock bitmap data
                source.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Y aca dejo el getpixel.

```
public Color GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            Color clr = Color.Empty;

            // Get color components count
            int cCount = Depth / 8;

            // Get start index of the specified pixel
            int i = ((y * Width) + x) * cCount;

            if (i > Pixels.Length - cCount)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            if (Depth == 32) // For 32 bpp get Red, Green, Blue and Alpha
            {
                byte b = Pixels[i];
                byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
                byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
                byte a = Pixels[i + 3]; // a
                clr = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
            }
            if (Depth == 24) // For 24 bpp get Red, Green and Blue
            {
                byte b = Pixels[i];
                byte g = Pixels[i + 1];
                byte r = Pixels[i + 2];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            }
            if (Depth == 8)
            // For 8 bpp get color value (Red, Green and Blue values are the same)
            {
                byte c = Pixels[i];
                clr = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
            }
            return clr;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the color of the specified pixel
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x"></param>
        /// <param name="y"></param>
        /// <param name="color"></param>
        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            // Get color components count
            int cCount = Depth / 8;

            // Get start index of the specified pixel
            int i = ((y * Width) + x) * cCount;

            if (Depth == 32) // For 32 bpp set Red, Green, Blue and Alpha
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
                Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
                Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
                Pixels[i + 3] = color.A;
            }
            if (Depth == 24) // For 24 bpp set Red, Green and Blue
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
                Pixels[i + 1] = color.G;
                Pixels[i + 2] = color.R;
            }
            if (Depth == 8)
            // For 8 bpp set color value (Red, Green and Blue values are the same)
            {
                Pixels[i] = color.B;
            }
        }
```

Todo funciona correctamente en ventanas de 32bits pero ya en una de 64 no funciona, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He visto que tienes en el código unos if donde compruebas que Depth es igual o distinto de 8, 24 y 32. ¿Y si pones otro if mirando si depth es igual a 64?. Igual es una tontería pero por probar